Expo 51 - ExpoLocation.startLocationUpdatesAsync has been rejected
I'm encountering an error when using the ExpoLocation.startLocationUpdatesAsync function in my application. The error message is:
Caused by: rd.c: Initializing task consumer 'fd.b' failed. Inherited error: fd.b.<init> [class android.content.Context, interface fc.e]] code: 'ERR_UNEXPECTED'

This error prevents me from capturing the user's location in the background.
This should be clear and understandable for a programmer familiar with location services and debugging in Expo or React Native.
Expo 51
package.json
"@expo/config-plugins": "~8.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-thin-svg-icons": "^6.5.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.2",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/tabs": "^0.0.0-alpha.12",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.36.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.3.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.17",
    "expo-asset": "~10.0.6",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "^13.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.3",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.12",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.19",
    "expo-jwt": "^1.6.5",
    "expo-location": "^17.0.1",
    "expo-print": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.17",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-sharing": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-sqlite": "~14.0.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.6",
    "expo-task-manager": "^11.8.2",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "mobx": "^6.12.0",
    "mobx-react-lite": "^4.0.5",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-mask-input": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-signature-canvas": "^4.7.2",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6"

app.json
    "android": {
      "permissions": [
        "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION",
        "android.permission.WAKE_LOCK",
        "android.permission.CAMERA"
      ]
    }

There’s a bug, and I need to capture the user's location.

I encountered a very similar error. This is possibly because of Proguard doing some magic under the hood. (I assume you have Proguard enabled too.) I had to add:
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-build-properties",
    {
      "android": {
        "compileSdkVersion": 34,
        "targetSdkVersion": 34,
        "buildToolsVersion": "34.0.0",
        "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
        "enableProguardInReleaseBuilds": true,
        "enableShrinkResourcesInReleaseBuilds": true,
        "extraProguardRules": "-keep class expo.modules.location.** { *; }" <-- This required
      },

// Rest of config..

Reference:

Expo Build Properties Docs
Github - Expo task consumer issue

